# How to organize swing stuff in Java (labels, buttons, anything)

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, organization, code-organization

I'm writing a Java program which is GUI (swing/awt stuff). Is it sensible to build the entire GUI in one method? That is, create and add every label, button, menubar, menu, menu item, etc.

Is there a better way to organize this? What about the events?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider making GUI with some GUI-editor instead of by hand. Netbeans has a decent GUI editorfor Swing.

Comment: My opinion and my experience in this and other fora is that using a GUI editor when one is learning Swing and GUI coding more often hampers this education of Swing than helps it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best to keep methods to a few lines of code, if possible, and never more than one screen-full. If your GUI is anything more than a few labels and a button, you probably want to break it up for readability. Have one createInputs() method, one createMenus() method, one createButtons() method, etc.

Follow a similar rule for event handlers: use anonymous classes if they're one or two lines of code, but anything more deserves to be in its own class with a name.

Comment: Another way to organize it is to use inheritance.  For example, you can subclass JPanel for part of the GUI.

Comment: @Matthew: No, it is not really sensible to create a subclass of JPanel if you don't need to overwrite some of the methods (for example for painting another background. You may create another class to bundle the functionality, but there is no reason it should extend from JPanel.

Comment: @Paŭlo, if the subclass provides significant pre-defined behavior (e.g. a particular layout, particular event listeners registered, etc.), I think it's a reasonable choice.

Comment: I have to go with Paulo on this one.  It can be dangerous to subclass when it is not needed.  See what happens if you subclass JPanel and just so happen to give it methods int getX() and int getY() and you'll see just how dangerous this is.  Only subclass when necessary.

Comment: @Hovercraft, it's easy to configure the compiler to warn about an override with a missing `@Override` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real "wrong way" to initialize a GUI; however, in my experience you can split up label/button creations into separate methods for readability.  Also, if you find multiple things in a single panel or tab etc... then you should look to extend JPanel and put everything in your constructor there.  Combining the JPanels will also help you to better layout the entire GUI.